# Cannot get Txt file to create from code

Tags: java, io

Good day. I am trying to get the code below to write to a txt file. Yet, I cannot get it to.  It just prints the code within the ("") on the output section.  My goal is to create the text file to store the output data to retrieve later.

```
public class Charlesshaw3Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        **//checking id command line argument provided
        if(args.length==0) {
            System.out.println("C:\\Users\\bryon\\Desktop\\Java Programming");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        String fileName = args[0];

        BufferedWriter out = null;

        try {
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(fileName);
            out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
        } 

        catch (IOException ex) {
           System.out.println("\nCould not create file: "+ fileName+".");
            System.exit(1);
        }**


    //a) 10 Instances of the violin testing.
    CharlesShaw3Tst voilin[] = new CharlesShaw3Tst[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        out.write("\n\n***Creating new violin object [" + (i + 1) + "]***");
        voilin[i] = new CharlesShaw3Tst();
        out.write("\nCreated");
        //b) tune your instruments,
        out.write("\nchecking if tuned?");
        out.write("\nVoilin tuned? " + voilin[i].isTuned());
        out.write("\nTuning...");
        voilin[i].setTuned(true);
        out.write("\nVoilin tuned? " + voilin[i].isTuned());
        //c) Start playing your instrument,
        out.write("\nVoilin playing? " + voilin[i].isPlaying());
        out.write("\nVoilin tuned? " + voilin[i].isTuned());
        out.write("\nCalling playVoilin method");
        voilin[i].playViolin();
        out.write("\nVoilin playing? " + voilin[i].isPlaying());
        // d) Call your unique method, and
        int num = voilin[i].getNumString();
        out.write("\nNumber of strings: " + num);
        out.write("\nString name: ");
        String strings[] = voilin[i].getviolinStrings();
        for (int s = 0; s < num; s++) {
            out.write(strings[s] + " ");
        }
        out.write("\n");
        //e) Stop playing your instruments.
        out.write("\nStopping playing..");
        voilin[i].stopViolin();
        out.write("\nVoilin playing? " + voilin[i].isPlaying());

        out.write("\nStopping tuning..");
        voilin[i].stopTuneViolin();
        out.write("\nVoilin tuned? " + voilin[i].isTuned());
    }
    //Close the output stream
    out.close();
}
}
```

Comment: What does " It just prints the code within the ("") on the output section" mean? Can you elaborate?

Comment: What is the `CharlesShaw3Tst` class supposed to do? Could you provide it's implementation?

Comment: Sean: the ("") refers to this: System.out.println("C:\\Users\\bryon\\Desktop\\Java Programming");

Answer (score 0):

Try using `FileWriter`'s append method:

```
try {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

    writer.append("Your string");
    //Append all strings

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();            
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous program it is referring to is:

public class CharlesShaw3Tst {

```
private final int numString = 5; // number of strings
private final String violinStrings[] = {"E", "B", "G", "D", "A"}; //an array of strings
//fields to determine if the instrument is tuned,
 private boolean tuned;
//and if the instrument is currently playing.
```

private boolean playing;
    //A constructor method that set the tuned and currently playing fields to false.

```
public CharlesShaw3Tst() {
    this.tuned = false;
    this.playing = false;
}
// Other methods

public boolean isPlaying() {
    return playing;
}

public void setPlaying(boolean playing) {
    this.playing = playing;
}

public boolean isTuned() {
    return tuned;
}

public void setTuned(boolean isTuned) {
    this.tuned = isTuned;
}

public void playViolin() {
    System.out.println("The violin is now playing.");
    playing = true;
}

public void stopViolin() {
    System.out.println("The violin is now playing.");
    playing = true;
}

public void tuneViolin() {
    System.out.println("The violin is tuned.");
    tuned = true;
}

public void stopTuneViolin() {
    System.out.println("The violin is tuned.");
    tuned = false;
}



public int getNumString() {
   return this.numString ;
}

public String[] getviolinStrings() {
    return violinStrings;
}
```

}